# React App with basename not working in production build, but works in development (create-react-app)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, create-react-app, webpack-production

I have created an app using **create-react-app** with a **basename** '/admin' and it is working just fine in development mode. All routes working properly both on localhost and behind nginx proxy.

When I build the app using `npm run build` I get a blank screen on the '/admin' url, with the following errors in the console:

> The script from “https://192.168.1.2/admin/static/js/main.49bb4878.js”
> was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid
> JavaScript MIME type.
>
> The stylesheet https://192.168.1.2/admin/static/css/main.4efb37a3.css
> was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' main.49bb4878.js:1

I have tried both `<BrowserRouter pathname="/admin">...</BrowserRouter>` and the one I have in the following `index.js` file.

It seems like the server sends the `index.html` file no matter what the client requests...

This is my `index.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import storeToConfigure from './configureStore';
import CustomRouter from './utils/CustomRouter';
import * as buffer from 'buffer';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
console.log(window);
window.Buffer = buffer;
window.process = {}

export const store = configureStore(storeToConfigure);

export const history = createBrowserHistory({ basename: '/admin' });

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <CustomRouter history={history} basename="/thug-app">
            <ScrollToTop>
                <App />
            </ScrollToTop>
        </CustomRouter>
    </Provider>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
reportWebVitals(console.log);
```

This is the `CustomRouter` I'm using, in order to be able to directly access the `history` anywhere without a hook:

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';

const CustomRouter = ({
    basename,
    children,
    history,
}) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        action: history.action,
        location: history.location,
    });

    useLayoutEffect(() => history.listen(setState), [history]);

    return (
        <Router
            basename={basename}
            children={children}
            location={state.location}
            navigationType={state.action}
            navigator={history}
        />
    );
};

export default CustomRouter;
```

Again, everything works just fine in development. The problem is when I build the app for production. I have tried both `pm2` and `serve` packages (same names on npmjs). The `serve` package returns `404`, while `pm2` returns the errors I mention above.

Thank you for taking the time to help!

Comment: Do you use serve with "serve -s build" and did you try both the localhost and network address? It does not seem like a path, basename, or routing issues. It is more an access/permission issue related to your local deployment. I'd recommend starting to debug the 404 of serve that you mentioned.

Comment: By using `serve -s build` I got the same problem with pm2. It seems like the server returns the `index.html` file no matter which file the client requests.

Comment: What is version of your 'history' dependency? From v5 there is no basename parameter for createBrowserHistory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work with this workaround:

I ditched both `pm2` and `serve` and used a custom `express.js` server.

The setup:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();

// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    
    let theUrl = req.originalUrl.replace('/admin', '');
    if (!!!theUrl) {
        theUrl = 'index.html';
    }

    try {
        const target = path.join(__dirname, 'build', theUrl);
        console.log(target);
        if (fs.statSync(target)) {
            res.sendFile(target);
        } else {
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
    }
});

app.listen(4000, () => console.log('admin app listening on 4000'));
```

It also seems to work fine without the following line:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
```

Like I had noticed, both `pm2` and `serve` sent the `index.html` file no matter what the client requested.

Seems to be working fine behind nginx proxy as well.

Whenever the requested file does not exist, simply serve the index.js file.